# $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ analysis book that uses Lebesgue integrals

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

A professor told me it would be unwise to study an $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ analysis book that uses Riemann integral. However, I do not know any book that doesn't. Is there something that covers material similar to Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, but using Lebesgue integrals instead? I don't think these topics are generally covered in a measure theory book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew Browder's *[Mathematical Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387946144)* does multivariable integral calculus using the Lebesgue integral. It is often overlooked because of classics like Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. It treats point-set topology, differential forms and Stokes's theorem too, totally awesome!

Comment: This looks nice. Maybe a bit repetitive since I'm already familiar with the first half of the book (up to and including topology), but if nobody suggests something better I might get it.